# Git merge with renames on one and same changes (formatter) on both sides

Tags: git, rename, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I've got two long living branches `develop` and `next`, where every commit in `develop` has to be in `next` as well.

The files in next have been moved to different folders.

Now I want to apply a formatter on the code base. I thought: If I apply the formatter on both branches, I won't get a merge conflict (at least of the files which aren't modified in `next` except by the formatter) when merging `develop` into `next`. But that doesn't seem to be true: the rename detection doesn't recognize the files have moved, so I end up with conflicts.

I even tried to merge with a lower setting for `find.renames`, despite it doesn't make sense, as most of the conflicted files in both branches are identical.

Is there an option I've overlooked?

Comment: Or is it just `git merge -s ours` what I'm looking for? 

Comment: Your best bet is probably to re-rename the files so that `git merge` matches up the correct files. Do the merge, then un-re-rename the files if needed. Note that each branch tip holds a snapshot, and `git merge` works by diffing a *third* commit—the merge base—snapshot against the two tip commit snapshots, one at a time, then combining work.

Comment: Using `git merge -s ours` is presumably entirely wrong as it means *don't bother diffing, don't even look at the other branch tip commit, just do the merge using the `HEAD` commit's snapshot*.

Comment: Mh, do think it's wrong even if I merge `develop` into `next` right *before* applying the formatter on both branches? I mean: the only conflicts are because of the undetected rename, there are no conflicts within the files.

Comment: Well, if you want the one input snapshot (`HEAD`) to match the result exactly, that *is* what `-s ours` does. But then why are you merging theirs at all? (Sometimes there is a reason, but one should know exactly what the reason is.)

Comment: So that the conflics are resolved as early as possible. Otherwise somebody else, whoever is merging `develop` into `next`, will suffer from the conflicts.

Comment: But `-s ours` doesn't *resolve* conflicts at all. It just nukes them entirely, paving everything else over with "ours". This *destroys* their work going forward (it's still there in history of course).